# Were Krishna and Vyasa able to see (not imagine) future?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, vyasa

According to some scenes in Star Plus Mahabharata and BR Chopra's Mahabharata (a TV series), it looks like both of them (Krishna and Vyasa) could see future. Did it actually happen in Vyasa Mahbharat?

Comment: Can you edit and explain what you mean by this: "Was it true?" - Do you mean: `1`) "Did it actually happen?" or "Is it really possible?" or `2`) "Is this story found in the original Vyasa Mahabharata?"

Comment: Do you really need to know about Krishna whether he was able to see future...? If yes then how you could even think that there is anything (exist or non-exist) which is beyond the visual range of krishna? Krishna covers every exist and non-exist entity in his visual range. He is palankarta, nothing is beyond his vision. Actually this is not even a question. No one can put question mark on capability of Lord Krishna :)

Comment: @Rishabh yes I really want to know :)

Comment: I forgot to tell you, type `1` questions are opinion-based hence will be closed. Because, you'd need a time machine to go back in time and verify if such a thing really happened. So you can only ask questions of type `2` (_Is the story, as narrated in the TV serial, really present in scriptures?_).

Comment: No he could not see the future. When he talked to Arjuna he was in connection with the Brahman then he was able to see it otherwise he could not.

Comment: Are you actually watching both versions of Mahabharata ? Or simply putting both in the question? Why even watch Star Plus version if you know it contains fictional stories ?

Comment: @ram yes I've watched both. The thing is I feel there's a lot of fiction in Star Plus (BR also had, but not that much), but I'm not sure about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your  enquiry is about  Shree krishna and Vyasa seeing  future  events mentioned in Mahabharata and the answer is Yes. Both of them were aware of the events going to happen during the Mahabharata time and this is mentioned in Mahabharata Itself .

Maharshi Vyasa was having divine vision and was capable of seeing future is mentioned in [**Mahabharata**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03007.htm) - Vana Parva-Aranya Parva - Chapter 7.

> तान प्रस्थितान परिज्ञाय कृष्णद्वैपायन: प्रभु : |
>  आजगाम
>   विशुद्भात्मा द्रष्टवा **दिव्येन चक्क्षुषा** || 23 ||
>
> P. 19 And knowing **by his spiritual vision** that they had gone out, the
>   master Krishna-Dwaipayana of pure soul came upon them, and commanded
>   them to desist.

Here we know that Vyasa was having divine vision and can able to see past and future.

---

In [**Mahabharata**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02045.htm) Sabha Parva-Dyuta Parva-Chapter-46 , we find Maharshi Vyasa telling what is going to come in the future to Yudhisthira. Vyasa thus told Yudhisthira that he officially will  be the sole  cause of the destruction of all Kshatriyas  in Kurukshetra war  for the sins of Duryodhana.

> Vaisampayana continued,--"Hearing these words of the king, the exalted
>   son of Parasara, the island-born Vyasa of dark hue, spoke these
>   words,--'For thirteen years, O king, those portents will bear mighty
>   consequences ending in destruction, O king of kings, of all the
>   Kshatriyas. In course of time, O bull of the Bharata race, making thee
>   the sole cause, the assembled Kshatriyas of the world will be
>   destroyed, O Bharata, for the sins of Duryodhana
>
> P. 92 and through the might of Bhima and Arjuna. In thy dream, O king
>   of kings thou wilt behold towards the end of this might the blue
>   throated Bhava, the slayer of Tripura, ever absorbed in meditation,
>   having the bull for his mark, drinking off the human skull, and fierce
>   and terrible, that lord of all creatures, that god of gods, the
>   husband of Uma, otherwise called Hara and Sarva, and Vrisha, armed
>   with the trident and the bow called Pinaka, and attired in tiger skin.
>   And thou wilt behold Siva, tall and white as the Kailasa cliff and
>   seated on his bull, gazing unceasingly towards the direction (south)
>   presided over by the king of the Pitris. Even this will be the dream
>   thou wilt dream today.

So from the above passage it's very clear that Vyasa was aware of future events at the time even at  Yudhisthira's Rajasuya Yajna.

Comment: Yout first quote mentions that Krishna saw the past not  the future.

Comment: @Wikash_ -  No , I haven't added Krishna's part in answer yet , that quote is about Vyasa. And divine vision is just like "Trikaldarshi"  that means a sage can see past future as well as present. Vyasa was having divine vision that means he was also capable to see the future and are well aware of that.

Comment: @Wikash_ We can also know from this shloka of Bhagvtam - https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/1/4/16/

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Krishna was able to see the future.

https://en.krishnakosh.org/krishna/Mahabharata_Udyoga_Parva_Chapter_89

> And that scion of Dasarha's race, that chief of the Vrishnis, **unto whom the past and the future were as the present**, knowing that Vidura was loved by the Pandavas and friendly towards them, and learned, and firm in morality, and honest, and harbouring no wrath (against the Pandavas), and wise, began to tell him everything in detail about the doings of the sons of Pandu.'"

https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02032.htm

> that invincible one as described by those that have knowledge, that foremost of all lasting existences in the universe, that origin of all things, as also that in which all things come to be dissolved, that **lord of the past, the future, and the present Kesava--the slayer of Kesi**

Vyasa also knew the future.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m18/m18005.htm

> It was explained (to us) by Vyasa of mighty energy, **celestial vision** and great prowess, that ancient ascetic, O Kauravya, who is the son of Parasara and who always observes high vows, who is of immeasurable understanding, **who is omniscient, and who, therefore knows the end attached to all acts.**

> I have now told everything that Vaishampayana narrated, at the command of Vyasa, unto the king at his snake sacrifice. Called a history, it is sacred, sanctifying and excellent. It has been composed by the ascetic Krishna, O Brahmana, of truthful speech. **He is omniscient**, conversant with all ordinances, possessed of a knowledge of all duties, endued with piety, capable of perceiving what is beyond the ken of the senses, pure, having a soul cleansed by penances, possessed of the six high attributes, and devoted to Sankhya Yoga. **He has composed this, beholding everything with a celestial eye that has been cleansed (strengthened) by varied lore. He has done this, desiring to spread the fame, throughout the world, of the high-souled Pandavas, as also of other Kshatriyas possessed of abundant wealth of energy.**

This clearly explains that Vyasa had celestial vision by which, he could see the past, the present, and also the future. He knew the end attained to all acts.